FastAPI dependency injection by class type
I'm familiar with dependency injecting and I was trying to do something I have seen in the past in other frameworks (spring Autowired annotation).
I have the following 2 classes :
class MyServerConfig:
    def __init__(self):
        serviceA_host = getenv("SERVICE_A_HOST")
        ServiceA_port = getenv("SERVICE_A_PORT")
        self._serviceA_addr = f"{serviceA_host}:{ServiceA_port}"

class DependencyContainer:

    def __init__(self, config: ServiceConfig):
        serviceA_channel = grpc.insecure_channel(config._serviceA_addr)
        self._serviceA_client = (
            SomeGrpcStub(serviceA_channel)
        )
    def service_a_client():
        return self.serviceA_client

In my main.py I initialize both classes and pass them as dependencies to my routes :
    config = MyServerConfig()
    dependency_container = DependencyContainer(config)

And I tried to pass them as dependencies to my inner routes :
    def get_dependency_container() -> DependencyContainer:
        return dependency_container

    def get_server_config() -> MyServerConfig:
        return config

    shared_dependencies = [
        Depends(get_server_config),
        Depends(get_dependency_container),
    ]

    app.include_router(
        somemodule.products_router_v1(),
        dependencies=shared_dependencies,
    )

My router code:
def products_router_v1():

    products_router = APIRouter(
        prefix="/products",
    )

    @products_router.post(
        "",
       
    )
    def register_product(
        save_request: SaveProductRequest,
        http_request: Request,
        dependency_container: DependencyContainer = Depends(),
    ) -> Response

I was hoping that fastapi will understand that DependencyContainer is available in the route dependencies and will inject it but it doesnt do that.
My goal is to create the clients in one place (main.py) and inject the relevant clients to the relevant endpoints. I prefer to create globals only in my main.py and not in other modules.
With the current code I'm getting the following exception:

astapi.exceptions.FastAPIError: Invalid args for response field! Hint: check that <class 'x.x.x.x.MyServerConfig'> is a valid Pydantic field type.

Is there a way to implement this injection via fastapi ?

Any reason for not injecting the actual clients necessary through Depends() (instead of using a dependency injection system to inject a dependency container) as is the common way to do it in FastAPI, instead of trying replicate how you'd do it in other frameworks?

Its a great idea, I tried injecting the specific client, but the problem is still the same. The client has also constructor with arguments (not a default one), and I didnt succeed to inject it by type, only had to provide a method that returns the instance which is something that i cant provide from inside the endpoint module.

You'd usually do something like def get_foo_client(config: Config = Depends(get_config)): return FooClient(config.foo_url, config.foo_api_key) for example, then have def endpoint(foo_client: FooClient = Depends(get_foo_client)): - Not sure what wouldn't work in that case?
